# how to make summation of two or more similar objects and prevent creating the new one if its exists ? django

Tags: python, django

i try to make a system for a storage , sometimes it happen two similar objects are entry in two different time , i have to summation the quantity of both and looks like one object instead of two different object
for example i've entry this data one week ago `name=mouse , qnt=20 , price=20` and today i add a new collection of mouse (the same mouse as before) `name=mouse , qnt=10 , price=15` i have to whenever i face similar problem it automatically summation quantities =(30) and price = ((20+15)/2) instead of creating a new object to the second mouse object
is it possible ? or is there anything else for similar issues ?!
this is my model

this is the Products model

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True) 
    qnt = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this is the Collections model

```
class Collections(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    qnt = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True)
```

i dont need to create new object to the same product as exist in collection , i have to just summation the quantities ?!
is it possible ?thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the save method of the model. For example:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True) 
    qnt = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3,null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        product = Products.objects.filter(name=self.name) 
        if product.count()>0:
            product.quantity = product.quantity + self.quantity
            product.price = (product.price + self.price)/2
            product.save()
            return
        else:     
            super(Products, self).save(*args, **kwargs
```

Comment: i thought about it as well , i'm not sure what logic should i make ! do you have any idea

Comment: I updated the code, I think it should work but not sure, not tested :).  Please give a try. I hope the logic is clear for you.

Comment: but it still create the new object

Comment: but we should overwrite the save method in Collections model

Comment: I think you are right, you can also overwrite save method in collections model. I think it should work.